# How to integrate YiiBooster for advanced theme Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app, yii-booster

i'm trying to integrate YiiBooster for a yii2 project. I'm working with the advanced theme but i'm stuck. I've used the composer to integrate and now i have: \vendor\vendor\clevertech\yii-booster\src.
I tried to download directly and configure by hand like says in the official website of yiibooster but i can't make it work.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii Booster was meant to work with Yii 1.x not Yii2. As such you cannot use it without rewriting the library to use Yii2.